# How does a controller class access a model class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How does this random controller class

```
class RandomController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user = User.all
  end
end
```

access the User class? I've been searching for the connection in the source files, but I can't seem to find a logical explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails has 'constant autoloading', so you don't need to add `require 'user'` to the top of your file.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html

When Rails encounters a missing constant, it tries to load a file with a filename based on the constant's name. This nearly always works smoothly... C-;